# iOS How can I draw small circle limit in the big circle in movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw, cgrect

I want to achieve the effect shown in [this github project](https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick), but I don't want to use SpriteKit to achieve this.

[image]

So I try to draw the big circle in the CircleViiew.m about the CGContextRef in Objective-C.

```
 #import "CircleView.h"
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 #define CIRCLE_RADIUS  80

 @implementation CircleView
 -(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andCircleRadius:(int) radius
 {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if(self)
     {   
     }
     return self;
 }

 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     // set rect background color
     CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y,rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 100.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);
     CGContextFillRect(context, drawRect);

     // set line border number
     CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,0.6,1,0.6,1.0);
     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
     CGContextAddArc(context, 82, 82, CIRCLE_RADIUS, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
     CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

// fill color
     UIColor *fillCircleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.800 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000];
     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillCircleColor.CGColor);
     CGContextAddArc(context, 82, 82, CIRCLE_RADIUS, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
     CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

     CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);   

 }
 @end
```

Then in the ViewController using the circle.

```
  CircleView *circle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 164, 164)];
     [self.view addSubview:circle];
```

But I don't know how to add the small circle overlay the big circle, and the small have to limit on the big circle when we movement the small circle.

Is create small circle object using CircleView on the viewDidload to overlay BigCircle? Or the small circle have to draw in the CircleView class?

I am using auto layout to create the effect. I don't know if I use `initwithFrame` to make, have generate problem after.

Can anyone give me some direction?

Answer (score 3):

Draw the small circle as a separate view, lying in front of (on top of) the big circle. It can be a UIImageView, for example.

Give the small circle a UIPanGestureRecognizer to make it draggable.

In the gesture recognizer handler, move the view to follow the user's gesture, *except* that you don't move the view if it would move further than a certain distance from the big circle's center.

Comment: First, thank your response. I will remove and add different the joy stick on the screen. If I add the ImageView on the uiviewcontroller, I can't easy to remove the stick. Have some method to wrap these to a object and easy to remove  the joystick? I wish the effect is click on the screen, the joystick will show on your click point, then old joystick will remove.If click in the big circle, it will not remove, the small will move to you click point.

Comment: "If I add the ImageView on the uiviewcontroller, I can't easy to remove the stick" Oh flapdoodle.

Comment: "click on the screen, the joystick will show on your click point, then old joystick will remove.If click in the big circle, it will not remove, the small will move to you click point" Fine, but that's a completely different question, isn't it? I answered the question you _did_ ask. Take it or leave it, use it or don't, vote it up or vote it down, but don't "leech" by asking completely new questions in the comments. If you have a new question, ask it as a new question.